# Add existing project to GitHub

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I've got an existing project that I need to add to `GitHub`.  I've got a local repo created and need to push it to **new** remote in `GitHub`.  My company uses `GitHub` for source control, so is this a "private" repo?  Anyway, I followed the steps outlined [here](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/) and get "Repository no found".  What am I missing?  This is not something I have much experience with.

```
git remote add origin https://myGitHubUrl/projectName ----COOL
git remote -v ----COOL
    *origin https://myGitHubUrl/projectName (fetch)*
    *origin https://myGitHubUrl/projectName (push)*
git push origin master ----NOT COOL
    *remote: Repository not found.*
```

**EDIT**
I missed the first step that says:

> *Create a new repository on GitHub. To avoid errors, do not initialize the new repository with README, license, or gitignore files. You can
>   add these files after your project has been pushed to GitHub.*

It works now.  ALWAYS READ THE DOCS!!

Comment: Can you `git fetch origin`? Does that work or does it lead to errors?

Comment: @omajid..."remote: Repository not found."

Comment: And I assume you did create the new repo on Github?

Comment: @Bzazz...No, I followed the GitHub instructions.  They don't say to create the new repo on GitHub first.  I don't mind doing that, however.

Comment: Always read the DOC... after stackOverflowing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the repository in github first and make sure the URL you use while configuring your local repository matches the one configured in github.

If you still have the same issue after creating the repository, take a look at their help page regarding this issue: [Here](https://help.github.com/articles/error-repository-not-found/)

Be aware that the help page uses SSH and not HTTPS. You may remain with the HTTPS protocol. Just copy the full link from what they provide on the repository page after you create it (by selecting HTTPS as your protocol) to be on the safe side.

Comment: I'd like to know why creating on GitHub first is necessary when it's not in the GitHub docs.  When I run remote -v it returns what is expected.  So isn't the remote project already there?

Comment: Git is a decentralized version controller. Meaning that you can still operate locally as long as you want. The same goes for anyone or any server. It means that your repository can  be initialized anywhere. But in order to synchronize the same repository across different servers, the minimum requirement is for these servers *to have the repository*. I don't think there is an automatic way of creating the repository. If so, I personally think it is a security issue. Think about a bot which creates 1000000 repos every minute.

Answer (score 1):

1) if you are trying to connect your local repo to a remote via https. If this is the case then the following commands should fix the issue for you:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/private-repo.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/private-repo.git (push)
$ git remote rm origin
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:private-repo.git
$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:private-repo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:private-repo.git (push)
```

2) Remove the remote origin

```
git remote rm origin
```

re-add the origin but with your username and pwd with writing privileges on this pvt repo

```
git remote add origin  https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@github.com/username/reponame.git
```

3) You have configured ssh key

```
#check current github account
ssh -T git@github.com

#ensure the correct ssh key used with github
ssh-agent -s
ssh-add ~/.ssh/YOUR-GITHUB-KEY

#re-add the origin
git remote add origin git@github.com:YOUR-USER/YOUR-REPO.GIT
git push -u origin master
```

4) you might need to try solved it by including my username and password in the repo url:

```
git clone https://myusername:mypassword@github.com/path_to/myRepo.git
```

Note: **This detailed step might help you and am considering you don't have repo created in github.**

Create a new repository on GitHub. To avoid errors, do not initialize the new repository with README, license, or gitignore files. You can add these files after your project has been pushed to GitHub.

```
    git init
    git add .
    git commit -m "First commit"

    # Sets the new remote
    git remote -v
    # Verifies the new remote URL
    git push origin master
```

**If it's exisiting github repo, then do following steps.**

```
cd existing_repo
git remote rename origin old-origin
git remote add origin <url>
git push -u origin --all
git push -u origin --tags
```

Comment: Please see my comment to @gumol.  Any thoughts on that?